# "add products" button missing from admin create order page - magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

We've just upgraded our site from 1.6.X to 1.7.0.2 and encountered this problem, 99% of the site is running fine.

When you go to sales/orders & create new order the "add products" button is missing? ive checked the styles and there is just a blank div where the button should be -

```
<div class="form-buttons"></div>
```

I've tried un-installing extensions, re-installing magento 1.7.0.2 from magento connect & i've also manually downloaded / over written the adminhtml folder, none of which have had any effect.

We also installed a fresh copy of magento with a blank database to the same server & the button is present.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes is in the file located here :

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Items.php around line 55

In previous version the getButtonsHtml() function was :

```
public function getButtonsHtml()
{
    $addButtonData = array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Add Products'),
        'onclick' => "order.productGridShow(this)",
        'class' => 'add',
    );
    return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')->setData($addButtonData)->toHtml();
}
```

The new version is :

```
public function getButtonsHtml()
{
    $html = '';
    // Make buttons to be rendered in opposite order of addition. This makes "Add products" the last one.
    $this->_buttons = array_reverse($this->_buttons);
    foreach ($this->_buttons as $buttonData) {
        $html .= $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')->setData($buttonData)->toHtml();
    }

    return $html;
}
```

So now you can have more than 1 button, but the first default button doesn't exists anymore.

I'm not sure how to add it without overwritting this block.

Comment: The problem is in the js, /js/mage/adminhtml/sales.js be sure to use the one from 1.7

Comment: the javascript files had not been updated, a permissions issue on the server stopped the update mid flow so we ended up with a mix of 1.6 & 1.7 files, Thanks for your help